# API testing using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, api, selenium

I am new to programming and testing API's and have done all the basics of selenium for browser calls. After running my browser functionalities with selenium, I have to invoke an API to complete a remaining functionality. The developer has provided an API to me with JSON input format. Can I do it in Selenium? and if yes, how can I do it?

for e.g, I am performing a transaction on an Ecommerce website using selenium. Now to invoke the refund for this transaction I have been provided an API where I will have to enter the Transaction ID of the transaction done earlier in JSON format.

Pls help

Comment: Your question lacks code, examples and an in-depth explanation. Please take your time to review and refine your question. Have you done any tutorials, familiarize yourself with Selenium and its functionality, conducted any trials? If you don't feel comfortable answering at least one of these questions positively, I suggest you study first.

Comment: My question is more about the approach that I should follow and its possibilities in selenium. As mentioned in my question, I have handled the browser part using selenium (i.e, performing a transaction on an Ecommerce website). Now to invoke the refund for this transaction I have been provided an API where I will have to enter the Transaction ID of the transaction done using browser in Java. Can I do this in Selenium and if yes, what should be the approach?

Comment: Selenium automates what a manual user would do in a browser environment, coping with html and Javascript. If your process can be handled this way then yes, Selenium would probably help you out. As for the approach, too little information is provided to advise properly. Is this transaction a one-off? Is it meant to be repeated? What is it triggered by? Back to my initial comment, please provide code and examples.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the explanation. The transactions would be done repeatedly and the ID's would be stored in excel. Upto this part I have done. Now I want to write something, where my script would pick these ID's from excel and hit the refund API. The input which refund API takes is JSON format. Can I do this part somehow in Selenium or do I need only Java to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't sound like Selenium is what you are looking for, although it may be helpful if you absolutely have to communicate through a browser. Something along the lines of what @pcjuzer will perhaps suit you better.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about Selenium. You should set-up your environment so that the frontend communicates with a **mock** backend. As one possible approach you can start a [mock backend](http://wiremock.org/docs/) on the same URL as on the real backend would be.

There are other possible solutions which involve replacing the real endpoint URL or communication channel on the HTML/JS with a test-URL during testing.